# Berkeley db compact always results in "Lock table is out of availalble object entries"

Tags: berkeley-db

I am running either:

```
CompactStats stats = data_db.compact(null, null, null, null, null);
```

or a version where I supply start and stop in increments of 10000 (our keys are long sequences) and repeat the call to compact.

At some point I always hit:
Lock table is out of availalble object entries

I have my Db normally running with MVCC which I tried turning off. I have configured 10k lockers 40k locks and 40k max object locks.

Some questions:

- What is the transaction management done here and shouldn't I expect every call to result in at least one transaction?
- What is it that can be using all those object entries?

Comment: Check http://techblog.beretti.org/post/2007/01/31/Lock-table-is-out-of-available-object-entries

Comment: Check http://bogofilter.sourceforge.net/faq.shtml#locksize